# Inequality composed of the min and max of a summation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $M$ is a non-negative matrix with dominant eigenvalue $\mu$. Let $s>\mu$.

$$\max_{1\le j\le n}\sum_{i=1}^n(sI-M)^{-1}_{ij} > \min_{1\le j\le n}\sum_{i=1}^n (sI-M)^{-1}_{ij}$$

Prove that the above inequality is not necessarily true.

Comment: I knew there was an inequality, but I was not sure which way the inequality should be. And if $\sum_{i=1}^n ( s I - M)^{-1}_{ij}$ is the same for each $1 \le j \le n$, then there is contradiction you want, as the LHS=RHS in the last step, instead of LHS > RHS.

Comment: If you want the question to reflect your work, you want that the above inequality is always a equality.

Comment: @Hetebrij. Hang on I still don't really understand that inequality. Let $$p_j = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (sI - M)^{-1}_{ij}$$ then we are left with $$\max_{1\le j\le n} p_j > \min_{1\le j \le n} p_j$$ which is clearly true as each finite set of real numbers has a maximum and minimum value. The only case this doesn't hold is if $p_1 = \ldots = p_n$.

Comment: Exactly. So your approach needs that $p_i = p_j$ for all $i,j$.

Comment: @Hetebrij So how can I show that $p_i=p_j$ for all $i, j$ then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inequality does not hold if $M$ is a positive scalar multiple of the identity matrix. More generally, this inequality does not hold (strictly) if all the column sums of $M$ are equal, i.e., if $\mathbf{1}^TM = \alpha\mathbf{1}^T$, for some positive scalar $\alpha < s$. To see this, observe that

$$
\mathbf{1}^T(sI - M) = (s - \alpha)\mathbf{1}^T \implies \mathbf{1}^T(sI - M)^{-1} = \frac{1}{s - \alpha}\mathbf{1}^T
$$

Note that since $M$ is nonnegative it follows that $\alpha = \mu$.
A class of matrices for which this holds true are the column stochastic matrices.

Comment: @KMiller Sorry, again I have changed the question as the answer didn't really suit the contradiction I require.

Comment: You should formulate your questions more clearly and carefully.

Comment: @user2850514: Why does K. Miller's answer not answer your question?